# Populating UITableView with JSON data from youtube videos in Swift 2 and Xcode 7

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview, parse-platform

I'm trying to build an app that is basically a youtube player. 
It has a UITableView where JSON data will be parsed from youtube according to the user's search (in the search bar) and present it on the cells with the video image, title and a  small description.

If the user clicks on the cell a new view opens and shows the video player where the user can play/stop/scrub and see more details about the video.

My question is how to exactly populate the cells with this data and how to link the next view with it.

Someone has any idea how to do this? Can you please show me the code on how to do it, or give me some advice on where to find the answer?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first have to create a UITable and implement the delegate methods together with a custom class that will act as cell for the UITable if you dont want the the deafult behaviour of the class.

For passing the data to the details you will use something called the segue you can have a look at the below project on github.

As for getting the data from youtube you will probably get a json response from youtube which you have to decode and add the objects to a list. You then just assign the object to the coressponding element like the below.

```
    //the view of every cell of the list
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    //custom cell identifier
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ViewControllerCell

    //setting up the images and casting them from strings to UIImages
    let imageURL = NSURL(string: JSONGameImages[indexPath.row])
    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: imageURL!)

    //setting game name, images and viewers on cells
    cell.gameName?.text = JSONGameName[indexPath.row]
    cell.gameViewers?.text = String (JSONViewers[indexPath.row])
    cell.gameImage?.image = UIImage(data: data!)


    return cell
}
```

https://github.com/renegens/Greenely

Comment: Hello Rene, thank you for your answer! I'm already a bit familiar with UITables and segues, my problem is how to parse the specific JSON data (thumbnail, title, description and video) from youtube to the cells.

Comment: Update on the answer.

Comment: Hey again Rene, thank you so much for your time! I haven't tried this yet because I'm still trying to understand how to get the JSON data from youtube, but I already used this same structure to create a table with custom cells :) 

I already have the tableView working with 3 videos that i manually inserted and I'm now going to learn how to use the youtube API and I guess Swifty JSON. You can see what I have now here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33637486/customcell-is-empty-or-results-in-sigabrt-error-w-code) Thanks!

Comment: Hello, no problem, it's better to get started with a lib like Swifty like you sugested cause if you are not using it you will end up in a for loop if numerous if let statemtents to get to the json object. With Swifty you can map the json to a class and use the class properties on it.