# CustomCell is empty or results in SIGABRT error [W/Code]

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, nsunknownkeyexception

I'm trying to create a video player that displays in a UITableView the thumbnails, titles and descriptions of the videos. When the user clicks on the raw it will open a new view with a WebView where the video will be played.

In the present moment I'm still trying to set the custom cell. I'm getting an error on the `AppDelegate.swift` file on the `class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {` line and the error is: `Thread 1: signal SIGABRT`. The error log is at the end of this post.

In the `Main.storyboard` I added a TableView (that I connected to the ViewController with the `delegate` and `dataSource`) with one prototype cell, where I added an ImageView and two labels. I also created a Swift File named `CustomTableViewCell.swift`. I set the `View Controller` Custom Class to ViewController, the identifier of the cell to `customCell`, style to "Custom" and it's class to `CustomTableViewCell`.

In the `ViewController.swift` I created an array with the information of the videos and I set the table functions.

I also tried other ways to write the code with solutions that I found here on Stack but I also get the same error or in the max I get a table with 3 empty cells. The code is down below. Can someone please tell how to put this custom cells working please?

Thanks in advance!

[image: Main.storyboard][image: Empty Cells with different code]

```
ViewController.swift

//
//  ViewController.swift
//  Cycloid
//
//  Created by smbss on 10/11/15.
//  Copyright © 2015 smbss. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

var videos = [Dictionary<String,String>()]

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if videos.count == 1 {

            videos.removeAtIndex(0)

            // Check if places != to 1 and not 0 because we created the dictionary places as a global var outside the ViewController and that can not be empty.

        }

        videos.append(["title":"Video 1","description":"Description 1","thumbnail":"http://img.youtube.com/vi/6oXTFb-52Zc/0.jpg","video":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6oXTFb-52Zc"])
        videos.append(["title":"Video 2","description":"Description 2","thumbnail":"http://img.youtube.com/vi/dkwuCeCQVg8/0.jpg","video":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dkwuCeCQVg8"])
        videos.append(["title":"Video 3","description":"Description 3","thumbnail":"http://img.youtube.com/vi/6Zf_70xM1Cw/0.jpg","video":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Zf_70xM1Cw"])

    }

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return 1
    }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return videos.count

    }

    /*
    //If I use this there is no SIGABRT error but the cells are empty.
        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            let cell:UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style:UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier:  "customCell")

            return cell

    */

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("customCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell

        let url = NSURL(string: videos[indexPath.row]["thumbnail"]!)
            let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)

        cell.img?.image = UIImage(data: data!)
        cell.ttl?.text = videos[indexPath.row]["title"]
        cell.dsc?.text = videos[indexPath.row]["description"]

        return cell

}

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

CustomTableView.swift

```
    //
    //  CustomTableViewCell.swift
    //  Cycloid
    //


    // import Foundation
    import UIKit

    class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

        @IBOutlet weak var img: UIImageView!

        @IBOutlet weak var ttl: UILabel!

        @IBOutlet weak var dsc: UILabel!

// I also tried deleting the code below.

        override func awakeFromNib() {
            super.awakeFromNib()
        }

        override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
            super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        }
    }
```

Error log:

```
2015-11-10 18:00:23.069 Cycloid[5922:398570] Unknown class CustomTableViewCell in Interface Builder file.
2015-11-10 18:00:23.074 Cycloid[5922:398570] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UITableViewCell 0x7f96da6a0030> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key dsc.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
        0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d55ef45 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
        1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010f282deb objc_exception_throw + 48
        2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d55eb89 -[NSException raise] + 9
        3   Foundation                          0x000000010d927a6b -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 288
        4   UIKit                               0x000000010de2f96f -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) setValue:forKey:] + 173
        5   UIKit                               0x000000010e133a71 -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 109
        6   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d49fa80 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 224
        7   UIKit                               0x000000010e132454 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1864
        8   UIKit                               0x000000010debe177 -[UITableView _dequeueReusableViewOfType:withIdentifier:] + 388
        9   UIKit                               0x000000010debe549 -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:] + 71
        10  Cycloid                             0x000000010d37a2dd _TFC7Cycloid14ViewController9tableViewfS0_FTCSo11UITableView21cellForRowAtIndexPathCSo11NSIndexPath_CSo15UITableViewCell + 125
        11  Cycloid                             0x000000010d37ac7f _TToFC7Cycloid14ViewController9tableViewfS0_FTCSo11UITableView21cellForRowAtIndexPathCSo11NSIndexPath_CSo15UITableViewCell + 79
        12  UIKit                               0x000000010ded0e2a -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 782
        13  UIKit                               0x000000010ded0f3f -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:willDisplay:] + 74
        14  UIKit                               0x000000010dea6307 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 3187
        15  UIKit                               0x000000010ded9d1c -[UITableView _performWithCachedTraitCollection:] + 92
        16  UIKit                               0x000000010dec1884 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 223
        17  UIKit                               0x000000010de2fe40 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 710
        18  QuartzCore                          0x00000001122c559a -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
        19  QuartzCore                          0x00000001122b9e70 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 366
        20  QuartzCore                          0x00000001122b9cee _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
        21  QuartzCore                          0x00000001122ae475 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 277
        22  QuartzCore                          0x00000001122dbc0a _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 486
        23  QuartzCore                          0x00000001122dc37c _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 92
        24  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d48a947 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
        25  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d48a8b7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
        26  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d47fe2c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 524
        27  UIKit                               0x000000010dd764f5 -[UIApplication _run] + 402
        28  UIKit                               0x000000010dd7b30d UIApplicationMain + 171
        29  Cycloid                             0x000000010d37be0d main + 109
        30  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010fd8a92d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

go to your storyboard, select the prototype cell, remove your custom class (so that is is a regular `UITableViewCell` again), build the project once, then set the custom class back to `CustomTableViewCell` and try again.

Comment: Thank you so much! At first I received an error but it was because I was not setting the app to allow http websites. Now it is working fine, great! :)

Comment: I tried but I receive a warning telling me that I don't have enough reputation to do it :/ It must be because my account is new... @raf

Comment: @ego.death no worries :)

Comment: Once I reach 15 in reputation I'll be sure to come back here ;) Can I ask one more thing? My cells are not displaying correctly. I wanted to make them bigger so I set a custom heigh for them but now the cells are not complete. You can see it here: [link](http://imageshack.com/a/img908/4321/RklnZq.png) and [link](http://imageshack.com/a/img907/1193/4b29Xn.png). Do you have any advice on this?

Comment: yeah sure. in the storyboard select your tableview (not the tableviewcell), go to the size inspector and set `row height` to 75 (or whatever height you want your cells to be).